# how do you iterate over a list in django

Tags: django, loops

This is a sample view code

```
def link(reqest):
    title  = ['Home Page', 'Current Time', '10 hours later']
    return render_to_response('time.html', title)
```

This is a sample template code

```
{% for item in title %}
    {{item}}
    {% if not forloop.last %} | {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This is a sample url code

```
(r'^now/$', current_time, link),
```

However, I get an error

> TypeError at /now/
>
> 'function' object is not iterable

I know this works in Python. How do you iterate in django, then?

Thank you for any input in advance!

---

from django error page

> TypeError at /now/
>
> 'function' object is not iterable
>
> Request Method:   GET Request URL:
>     http://127.0.0.1:8000/now/ Django
>   Version:  1.2.3 Exception Type:
>     TypeError Exception Value:
>
> 'function' object is not iterable
>
> Exception Location:
>     C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py
>   in resolve, line 121 Python
>   Executable:   C:\Python27\python.exe
>   Python Version:   2.7.0 Python Path:
>     ['C:\Documents and
>   Settings\JohnWong\workspace\mysite\mysite',
>   'C:\Documents and
>   Settings\JohnWong\workspace\mysite',
>   'C:\Python27', 'C:\Python27\DLLs',
>   'C:\Python27\lib',
>   'C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk',
>   'C:\Python27\lib\plat-win',
>   'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages',
>   'C:\WINDOWS\system32\python27.zip']
>   Server time:  Sat, 16 Oct 2010
>   22:45:36 -0400
>
> Environment:
>
> Request Method: GET Request URL:
>   http://127.0.0.1:8000/now/ Django
>   Version: 1.2.3 Python Version: 2.7.0
>   Installed Applications:
>   ['django.contrib.auth', 
>   'django.contrib.contenttypes', 
>   'django.contrib.sessions', 
>   'django.contrib.sites', 
>   'django.contrib.messages'] Installed
>   Middleware:
>   ('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
>   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
>   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
>   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')
>
> Traceback: File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py"
>   in get_response
>     91.                         request.path_info) File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in resolve
>     217.                     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path) File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in resolve
>     121.             kwargs.update(self.default_args)
>
> Exception Type: TypeError at /now/
>   Exception Value: 'function' object is
>   not iterable

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to iterate over this thing, right?

```
title  = ['Home Page', 'Current Time', '10 hours later']
```

Well, `link` is a function (you `def`'d it, remember?) so you can't just access `title` like that. That code will not work in Python. If you try this:

```
def link(reqest):
    title  = ['Home Page', 'Current Time', '10 hours later']
    return render_to_response('time.html', title)

for item in link.title:
    print title
```

You'll also get an error:

> `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'title'`

Comment: I'm having a str list `"[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]"`. I'm getting **ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got '['.**

Answer (score 0):

This is about how you're specifying the context for the template, I believe. Try returning a dictionary instead, with `title` inside of it:

```
return render_to_response('time.html', {"title":title})
```

and then iterating like:

```
{% for item in title %}
    {{ item }}
```

etc.

Note that you need two brackets around `item` in the loop, rather than one.

---

Now that you've added the extra info, I see the error is coming before the view is even executed (though you would have had a few once you got there, too).

The URL specification takes a callable as it's second argument. You have a couple of variables on there -

```
(r'^now/$', current_time, link),# that isn't a proper reference to the 'link' function, and it can't come second
```

It should be something like

```
(r'^articles/(?P<current_time>\(?P<link>)/$', 'project_name.views.link'), #the second tuple element is the view function
```

and then to accommodate the variables you are apparently passing in the URL, (also, make sure to have 'request' and not 'reqest' to keep things straight)

```
def link(request,current_time,link):
```

Comment: I tried your and the previous poster's method, and I am still getting the same error. so weird.

Comment: @JohnWong have you inspected the context/local variables section of the Django error page to see what entries it has for `list` or `title`?

Comment: I am quite new to django. Beside the setting, the rest are posted (i updated the thread). I don't see an error related to list at all?

Comment: @JohnWong Okay, I'm updating my post.

Comment: after searching on google, i think that's capturing the link from URL? i implemented it and it still doesn't work (of course i changed it to now, instead of articles, and replace project_name with mysite (my project name)..... ) i am getting "no url matched". I basically had a function called current_time, and another one called link. I have one template called "time.html". And I want to use both view functions on the time.html. Of course I can do it in a single view function. But in general, we might have n-th view functions to pass and use on the same html. But thanks for ur input so far!!!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't made a context.  You're passing a list where a context is needed, and using a view name in the template.  Try this:

```
def link(request):
    c = Context()    
    c['titles'] = ['Home Page', 'Current Time', '10 hours later']
    return render_to_response('time.html', c)
```

and then:

```
{% for item in titles %}
    {{item}}
    {% if not forloop.last %} | {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: If you're using `render_to_response`, you can simply specify a dictionary rather than a context object.